# Excel vba consistently unable to find file

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to copy data from a specific cell in one workbook, and paste it into another.
I have tried probably half a dozen codes that I found online, many from this website.
No matter which code I try, I always get the `1004 error: unable to find file` error message.

The latest code that I am trying is

```
Sub COPYCELL()
    Dim wbk As Workbook

    strFirstFile = "c:\test\tugboat.xlsx\"
    strSecondFile = "c:\test\zzzzmaster.xlsm\"

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
    With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
        Range("A3").Copy
    End With

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)
    With wbk.Sheets("Sheet1")
       Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, 
    SkipBlanks:=  _
    False, Transpose:=False
End With
```

End Sub

[Here is an image of the file properties, just to verify that I'm not doing something stupid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM8PB.png)

I know you guys get this question often, but I haven't been able to find anything that solved this for me. If anyone could lend me a hand it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Remove the backslash from the end of the file names. Also, your `With` blocks aren't doing anything - it should be `.Range("A3")` in both and not just `Range("A3")`, or just remove them as they are actually making the code longer!

Comment: Oh jesus christ. I knew it was going to be something stupid, thank you, that worked. Thank you for the very quick response.

I'm new to this site, is there a way to flag this as solved besides just editing post name?

Comment: What workbook is your macro in? Is it in zzzzmaster.xlsm? If so, it should already be opened to run your macro, so you don't need to open it.

Comment: It is being run from a third workbook

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the macro from zzzzmaster.xlsm, you can shorten your code

```
Dim wbk As Workbook

strFirstFile = "c:\test\tugboat.xlsx"

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wkb.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A3").Value
```

If you are running the macro from a third workbook

```
Dim wbk As Workbook
Dim wbk2 As Workbook

strFirstFile = "c:\test\tugboat.xlsx"
strSecondFile = "c:\test\zzzzmaster.xlsm"

Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(strFirstFile)
Set wbk2 = Workbooks.Open(strSecondFile)

wkb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value = wkb.Sheets(Sheet1).Range("A3").Value
```

Comment: You should also remove the last \ from `strFirstFile`

Comment: Updated per comments